# parent div is not expanding to height

Tags: css

I have a simple markup:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="position: absolute;">
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXKHh/)

Why the heck is the parent div not expanding the height?

Edit:

The final markup is something like this:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="position: absolute;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
</div>
```

I'm using [jquery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). So `position: absolute` is necessary and added automatically by the plugin.

Comment: I think overflow auto work here as suggested by @Nathan Lee. I also think so here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Akki619/aXKHh/9/

Comment: I need to have `position: absolute`. so it's not working: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXKHh/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue, it appears, is that your Cycle slideshow is collapsing because each slide (the image in your markup) has `position: absolute` set.

This is necessary because Cycle uses positioning (along with other CSS) to transition the slides. To solve this, look at either setting a fixed height on the container (only an option if your site is fixed-width). Cycle 2 has an [auto-height option](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/autoheight.php), which:

> ...determines whether or not Cycle2 will provide height management for the slideshow which can be very useful in fluid or responsive designs. There are three ways this option can be used:
>
> - an integer can be provided to identify the zero-based slide index for a sentinel slide
> - the string "calc" can be provided to instruct Cycle2 to calculate the tallest slide and use it as the sentinel
> - a ratio string can be provided which identifies the width:height aspect ratio for the container
>
> By default, the slideshow's first slide is used as the sentinel slide and its demensions will control the height of the slideshow container if the container does not have a specific height set via CSS.

Some advice: use Cycle 2 (as opposed to the original Cycle plugin), it's got what you need built-in. Also check out the very good [API documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/).

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about cycle 2. I thought with `position: relative` on parent it's not collapsing.

Answer (score 5):

Because you have `position: absolute;` there. Change it to `position: static;` or similar. Why do you want to use absolute positioning there?

Comment: I can't change it because it's added automatically by javascript cycle.

Comment: Change the cycle then, add your cycle.

Comment: he has absolute positioned image, not the div

Comment: @Mr.Alien - this is not the case, absolute positioning never expands parent's height.

Comment: You can still run a script after the cycle plugin and change the css of those images... But I think rather you're doing something wrong. Perhaps you need to specify a container for all the cycle images or define the min-height for them. I used cycle long ago, but don't remember having problems with it.

Comment: I can't use static cause there are more than one images in the parent div. Only one image is visible.

Comment: @Kamo I just got the scenario, I guess am sleepy :)

Comment: @redreggae - I don't know what you want to achieve, but I'd give a try min-height, suggested by Shomz

Comment: @Mr.Alien - happens :)

Comment: @Kamo I thought that he wanted the parent to be 100%.. well thanks anyways to point out the mistake, here goes +1

Comment: I've edited my question. So `position: static` is not an option.

Comment: Then set fixed height to the parent div(assuming your images have same dimensions).